# exec in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

To take the number of test cases and output all the input numbers, I can do the following in Python 2.5

```
exec"print input();"*input()
```

How to do it in Python 3, in shortest possible way?

Comment: Down vote why do you need exec?

Comment: -1 "Shortest possible way" is code golf, and wrong, unless you have a specific and very good reason. It should be *clearest* possible way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your obfuscated code works just fine in Python 3 too, once you have adapted for the changes, which can trivially be done by running the code through 2to3.

```
exec("print(input());"*eval(input()))
```

(Although eval should in this case be replaced with int() as that's what you want.)
Obviously, this is all ridicolous, why are you using exec and multiplication of strings instead of loops?

```
for ignored in range(int(input())):
    print(input())
```

You can also do it with a list expression:

```
[print(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

Although most people would say (and I would agree) that using list expressions for it's side effects or to loop is generally bad form. List expressions should be used to create lists.

This is a piece of clear and self-documenting code that does the same:

```
num_integers = int(input('How many integers do you want to input? '))
for x in range(num_integers):
    print(input('Integer {}: '.format(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't use a loop?

```
for _ in xrange(input()):
    print input()
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec`, like `print`, is a function call in Python 3. Wrap the string in parentheses.

Comment: I am aware of that. I need help regarding the `*input()` part.